# Laravel 4: Relationship not by row id

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relationship

Hi there I have a model called Friend that has an id, and user_id, and a friend_id. 
I want to make a relation to the user model that goes not by the row id on friend, but rather the user_id on friend. AKA if I do `hasOne('User', id);` it will take the id for the row on friend and do something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = <friend_row_id>` Rather I would have it be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = <friend_user_id>` Do I have to do this manually? Or is there a way to define this relation?

P.S. I'm new to relations so if I'm asking something kind of dumb, sorry!

EDIT:
Here's the code I have atm.

```
$ret = array();
        if(Auth::check()){
            $friend = new Friend();
            $ret['friends'] = $friend->where('friend_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        }
        error_log(print_r(DB::getQueryLog(),true));
    return View::make('index.index', $ret);
```

the Friend model has the function declaring the relationship as follows:

```
public function user(){
        $this->hasOne("User");
    }
```

The Friend and User tables are:

```
  Friend             User
    ///////////////    /////////////
    // id        //    // id      //
    // user_id   //    // email   //
    // friend_id //    // password//
    ///////////////    // name    //
                       /////////////
```

With this everytime I get a row from friend, it should get the associated user as well correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the User model is related to the Friend model by the `user_id` field on the friend model, then this should be fine:

```
return $this->hasOne('User');
```

Laravel will not use the row ID, it will automatically assume the key to the User model is `user_id`. If you want to be more explicit about this, you can be:

```
return $this->hasOne('User', 'user_id');
```